# SQL Query to Find Top 80% of Contribution

Tags: sql

I'm looking to find out how to write a SQL query that looks for store locations that contribute towards 80% of inventory adjustments and what their inventory accuracy calculation is. I'm not quite sure how to go about doing it. So far I have the total absolute value of their adjustments which will be used to base the calculation off of. Here's what I have so far.Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT  sum(abs(Details.ValueDifference)) As writeoff, (sum(Details.NumberofPartsCounted) - sum(Details.NumberofPartsCountedwithErrors))/(sum(Details.NumberofPartsCounted)) As Accuracy
FROM Details;
```

Comment: It would help if you shared your table structure (the name and columns of every table involved and some sample data that might be in it), as well as a sample of what you want the results of the query to look like. It's difficult to give advice on how to change your query without that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Shannon. I'm just doing a query on one table.The table has a structure like this:    Location Number, Number of Parts Counted, Number of parts Counted With Errors, and Value Difference which is simply the dollar value of inventory adjustments.  The end result I'm looking for is just the accuracy percentage for those locations that made up 80% of the total absolute dollar value of adjustments. Is there any way I can embed images here? That might make this easier.

Comment: It is possible to embed images (see here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post). If you don't have enough reputation to add them yourself, you could comment with the links and someone else could edit them into your question for you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to create links to my image.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, well, I feel like I'm not 100% confident in terms of what you're looking for, but here's my best guess. It looks like you want to select location number along with what you're referring to as "writeoff" and "Accuracy" in your query. You'll have to group by the location number in order to get the sums for each location.

It sounds like the writeoff results column is supposed to help tell you how much a particular location has contributed towards total inventory adjustments? Assuming that's true, I would also order by writeoff in descending order so you can see the rows with the highest values for this first.

```
 SELECT N_LOCATION
       ,sum(abs(ValueDifference)) As writeoff
       ,(sum(NumberofPartsCounted) - sum(Details.NumberofPartsCountedwithErrors))/(sum(NumberofPartsCounted)) As Accuracy
   FROM Details
  GROUP BY
        N_LOCATION
  ORDER BY
        writeoff DESC;
```

Honestly, I think the best way to accomplish what I think you're trying to do would be with a stored procedure. I would use the query above and also a query to select the sum of the absolute value of the value difference for all locations. Then I would save the total for all locations in a variable to be used while looping through the results of the first query. That way, you can use the "writeoff" for the location with the total for all locations to find the percentage for each location.

I'm guessing you would then add locations to a result set until the locations that you've added have percentages totaling 80%? Not sure exactly how you're setting the rule for that 80%, but hopefully you can adjust as needed.

Comment: I was able to get closer using this in sqlite:  select  abs(sum(Details.ValueDifference))/(select abs(sum(Details.ValueDifference)) from Details) pct_to_total
from details
group by Details.ServiceCenterNumber
order by pct_to_total desc;